# SQL Query to return Sum of items by user and date

Tags: postgresql, express

I have an Express Api, using postgresql.

I currently use the following query to populate a leaderboard:

```sql
SELECT acts.users_id, username, avatar_url, COUNT(acts.id)
FROM acts
    RIGHT JOIN users ON acts.users_id = users.id
    JOIN memberships on memberships.users_id = users.id
WHERE memberships.groups_id = ' + req.params.group_id + '
GROUP BY acts.users_id, username, avatar_url
ORDER BY COUNT(acts.id) DESC
```

This returns a list of users all belonging to a specific group listed in descending order of the number of "acts" by each user.

I am trying to modify this query to only include acts that were created within the last eg 7 days.

I have tried this modified query:

```sql
SELECT acts.users_id, acts.created_at, username, avatar_url, COUNT(acts.id)
FROM acts
    RIGHT JOIN users ON acts.users_id = users.id
    JOIN memberships on memberships.users_id = users.id
WHERE memberships.groups_id = ' + req.params.group_id + '
    AND acts.created_at >= (CURRENT_DATE - 7)
GROUP BY acts.users_id, acts.created_at, username, avatar_url
ORDER BY COUNT(acts.id) DESC
```

this modified query returns the correct data, but it separates by date, so I get multiple rows for each user instead of totals by user.  I assume this is due to including created_at within group_by. However, if I remove it, I get the error:

```
error: column "acts.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Remove the date from the select list.

Comment: @forpas, just tried your suggestion. no change in the data output

Comment: My suggestion is about the error you get in the 2nd query. You can't select a column which is not in the group by clause.

Comment: makes sense. My question is how to do the exact query, but limit it to acts created within eg the last 7 days.  That's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT acts.users_id, username, avatar_url, COUNT(acts.id)
FROM acts
    RIGHT JOIN users ON acts.users_id = users.id
    JOIN memberships on memberships.users_id = users.id
WHERE memberships.groups_id = ' + req.params.group_id + '
    AND acts.created_at >= (CURRENT_DATE - 7)
GROUP BY acts.users_id, username, avatar_url
ORDER BY COUNT(acts.id) DESC
```

You do not need to group by a field or select a field for filtering by this field. Just add the condition and do not change anything else.

This is what @forpas meant, I guess.